# Google finance API - trouble fetching currency rates

Tags: php, mysql, google-api, currency

I'm using Google's currency API to fetch exchange rates and store them in my database, but I ran into some problems. Here's what I'm working with:

```
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100USD=?GBP
```

I'm always passing 1USD as the first parameter and exchange that to all the currencies in my database, cast the result variable as a float and store it. Everything works fine until the result from the API is greater than 1000. For example:

`http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100USD=?PYG`
This returns "440 528.634" as the value, and the problem is in the space delimiter. When I cast that to a float it only stores "440". I tried running str_replace() on it before i cast it to a float, but for some reason that doesn't work - I'm guessing it's not a regular whitespace but a special character of some sort. I also tried exploding the variable by a space and returning the merged array fields, but no dice. I'm running out of ideas here so I really hope someone can help me on this :D

Comment: It's [`U+00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/), NO-BREAK SPACE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a non-breaking space character. You can replace it if you refer to it as `\xA0`:

```
$result = str_replace("\xA0", "", $result);
```

Note the double quotes. Use those instead of single quotes as it won't work correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Its NO BREAK SPACE. You should refer to it as `\xA0`

```
$x = str_replace("\xA0", "", $x);
```

Should work.